# How to find out if application runs slowly?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, performance, task-parallel-library

I'm currently developing some sort of I/O-pipeline system. Simply said: You can run simultaneous workers which do some stuff, either import or export data. I don't want to limit the user in how many workers will run simultaneously as performance, logically, depends on how they work.

If one wants to import 30 small images simultaneously, then he shall do this. But I want to equip my application with a monitor which notices when the application, especially the main thread, runs to slow, so that it will lag visibly. If this happens, the pipeline should reduce the amount of workers and maybe pause some of them in order so stabilize the application.

Is there any way to do this? How can I effectively monitor the speed, so I can say it is definetly to slow?

EDIT:
Okay I may have been a bit unclear. Sorry for that. The problem is more the status invokes. The user should be able to see what's going on. Therefore every worker invokes status updates. This happens in real-time. As you can imagine, this causes massive lags as there are a few hundred invokes per second. I tackled this problem by adding a lock which filters reports so that just every 50ms a report gets really invoked. The problem is: It still causes lags when there are about 20-30 workers active. I thought the solution was: Adjusting the time-lock by the current CPU load.

Comment: This is a bit off topic, but if most of your work is I/O bound operations, you can use async IO without any need for threads

Comment: If you use .NET's TPL, you can queue as many `Task`s as you want. The TPL will handle splitting the work out to the number of threads necessary to maximize performance.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit unclear what I mean. I edited the inital post.

Comment: Updating the UI every 50 ms shouldn't cause any noticeable lag and I don't think adjusting the update frequency is the right solution here. My guess is that there is something wrong with your time lock, you might want to ask a new, more specific question about that.

Answer (score 0):

> But I want to equip my application with a monitor which notices when the application, especially the main thread, runs to slow, so that it will lag visibly.

I don't quote understand this. I believe there are two common cases of UI lag:

1. Application that runs significant amounts of CPU-bound code on the UI thread or that performs synchronous IO operations there.
2. Showing way too many items in your UI, like a data grid with many thousand rows. Such UI is not useful to the user, so you should figure out a better way of presenting all those items.

In both cases, the lag can be avoided and you don't need any monitor for that, you need to redesign your application.

Comment: I know that this is avoidable. And that's what I'm looking for, how to avoid that. Please check the inital post, I updated it to be more clear about the situation. That's what this is about, how to avoid it ;)